# VB.NET: use "Or" with a "equal or greater than" in a "If" statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I cannot get me If statement to work properly.

I want my If statement to check my two textboxes: Name and Price, so that they are not empty and also check the Price textbox so the input price/number is equal or greater to 1.00.

Right now, the program warns me even if I type in a number/price higher than 1.00, something it only should do when the number is less than 1.00.

I am using: Option Explicit On, Option Strict On.

```
 Private Sub Btn_ResrvCancl_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_ResrvCancl.Click, listBox_ResDisplay.DoubleClick
        If listBox_ResDisplay.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            If radioBtn_Reserve.Checked Then
                If txt_Name.Text Is "" Or txt_Price.Text Is "" Or CDbl(txt_Price.Text) > 1.0 Then

                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter both your name and price (price must be 1.00 or higher)")

                Else

                    Dim BookingSuccess As Boolean = seatmgrResrv.NewReservation(txt_Name.Text, CDbl(txt_Price.Text), CInt(listBox_ResDisplay.SelectedItem.ToString.Substring(0, 15).Trim))
                    If BookingSuccess = False Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Already booked!")
                    End If
                    End If
                Else
                    Dim CancelSuccess As Boolean = seatmgrResrv.CancelReservation(CInt(listBox_ResDisplay.SelectedItem.ToString.Substring(0, 15).Trim))
                    If CancelSuccess = False Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Already vacant!")
                    End If
                End If

                UppsateList()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose a seat")
            End If
    End Sub
```

For what I understand, this must be the row that are incorrect but I cannot figure out a solution:

```
If txt_Name.Text Is "" Or txt_Price.Text Is "" Or CDbl(txt_Price.Text) > 1.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Is` operator is for referential equality, i.e. whether two references refer to the same object, while you want value equality, for which you use the `=` operator.  The compiler might optimise such that either will work but that's not a reason not to do it properly.

Also, you can't really use `CDbl` because it will throw an exception if the `TextBox` is empty or contains some other non-numerical value.  If you were to use `OrElse` instead of `Or` then that would handle the empty case but not any other.

Finally, you want to notify the user if the amount is LESS THAN 1, not if it's greater than.

All up, this is what your code should look like:

```
Dim price As Decimal

If txt_Name.Text = String.Empty OrElse
   Not Decimal.TryParse(txt_Price.Text, price) OrElse
   price < Decimal.One Then
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
CDbl(txt_Price.Text) >= 1.0 Then
```

will cause your validation message to show when the price is **greater than or equal to** 1.0. Really you should be checking if the value is strictly less than 1.0:

```
CDbl(txt_Price.Text) < 1.0
```

Comment: You are right @Brian, thanks! I've now changed it but, unfortunately, it doesn't fix my problem. I can still use 0 or less.